# Link simillary name classes so that when one is clicked the other is given a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, code-cleanup

Basically, I'm asking for a way to optimize this code. I'd like to cut it down to a few lines because it does the same thing for every click bind.

```
    $("#arch-of-triumph-button").click(function(){
        $("#arch-of-triumph-info").addClass("active-info")
    });
    $("#romanian-athenaeum-button").click(function(){
        $("#romanian-athenaeum-info").addClass("active-info")
    });
    $("#palace-of-parliament-button").click(function(){
        $("#palace-of-parliament-info").addClass("active-info")
    });
```

Is there a way to maybe store "arch-of-triumph", "romanian-athenaeum", "palace-of-parliament" into an array and pull them out into a click bind? I'm thinking some concatenation maybe?

```
$("+landmarkName+-button").click(function(){
    $("+landmarkName+-info").addClass("active-info")
});
```

Is something like this even possible?
Thanks in advance for all your answers.

EDIT: Here's the full HTML.

```
        <div class="landmark-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content landmark">
                <div class="heading span-after">
                    <span>Arch of Triumph</span>
                </div>
                <div class="landmark-button" id="arch-of-triumph-button"></div>                 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="landmark-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content landmark">
                <div class="heading span-after">
                    <span>Romanian Athenaeum</span>
                </div>
                <div class="landmark-button" id="romanian-athenaeum-button"></div>                  
            </div>
        </div>


----------------------------------------------------------

        <div class="landmarks-info-wrapper">
            <div class="landmark-info" id="arch-of-triumph-info">
                <div class="info-landmark section">
                    <span class="landmark-title">Arch of Triumph</span>
                    <span class="landmark-coord">44°28′1.99″N 26°4′41.06″E</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="landmark-info" id="romanian-athenaeum-info">
                <div class="info-landmark section">
                    <span class="landmark-title">The Romanian Athenaeum</span>
                    <span class="landmark-coord">44.4413°N 26.0973°E</span>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Sure. So there's a button that looks like this `<div class="landmark-button" id="arch-of-triumph-button"></div>` I'd like to link this button with another div `<div class="landmark-info" id="arch-of-triumph-info"></div>` and give it a class of "active-info". Notice how the only difference between to two id names is the particles "-button" and "-info". I'm trying to use that to the code's advantage.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot!

Comment: If you want to declutter the HTML and not rely on having all of those repetitive IDs for each button and each info, see my answer - you can just check the index of the clicked button in the button collection, and then select the item at the same index in an array of infos. I think that method is a whole lot cleaner than using IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not able to modify your HTML markup (in which case with use of CSS classes would be cleaner), a solution to your question would be as shown below:

```js
// Assign same click handler to all buttons
$("#arch-of-triumph-button, #romanian-athenaeum-button, #palace-of-parliament-button")
.click(function() {

  // Extract id of clicked button
  const id = $(this).attr("id");

  // Obtain corresponding info selector from clicked button id by replacing
  // last occurrence of "button" pattern with info.
  const infoSelector = "#" + id.replace(/button$/gi, "info");

  // Add active-info class to selected info element
  $(infoSelector).addClass("active-info");
});
```

Comment: Amazing. This worked like a charm and I've been looking for a solution this simple and elegant for a very long time. Superb job and thank you for answering so fast.

Answer (score 0):

Because each `.landmark-button` looks to be in the same order as its related `.landmark-info`, you can put both collections into an array, and then when one is clicked, just find the element with the same index in the other array:

```
const buttons = [...$('.landmark-button')];
const infos = [...$('.landmark-info')];
$(".landmark-button").click(function() {
  const i = buttons.indexOf(this);
  $(infos[i]).addClass('active-info');
});
```

This does not rely on IDs at all - feel free to completely remove those from your HTML to declutter, because they don't serve any purpose now that they aren't being used as selectors.

Live snippet:

```js
const buttons = [...$('.landmark-button')];
const infos = [...$('.landmark-info')];
$(".landmark-button").click(function() {
  const i = buttons.indexOf(this);
  $(infos[i]).addClass('active-info');
});
```

```css
.active-info {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landmark-wrapper">
  <div class="page-content landmark">
    <div class="heading span-after">
      <span>Arch of Triumph</span>
    </div>
    <div class="landmark-button" id="arch-of-triumph-button">click</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="landmark-wrapper">
  <div class="page-content landmark">
    <div class="heading span-after">
      <span>Romanian Athenaeum</span>
    </div>
    <div class="landmark-button" id="romanian-athenaeum-button">click</div>
  </div>
</div>


----------------------------------------------------------

<div class="landmarks-info-wrapper">
  <div class="landmark-info" id="arch-of-triumph-info">
    <div class="info-landmark section">
      <span class="landmark-title">Arch of Triumph</span>
      <span class="landmark-coord">44°28′1.99″N 26°4′41.06″E</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="landmark-info" id="romanian-athenaeum-info">
    <div class="info-landmark section">
      <span class="landmark-title">The Romanian Athenaeum</span>
      <span class="landmark-coord">44.4413°N 26.0973°E</span>

    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Older answer, without knowing the HTML: You can extract the ID of the clicked button, slice off the `button` part of it, and then select it concatenated with `-info`:

```
$(".landmark-button").click(function() {
    const infoSel = this.id.slice(0, this.id.length - 6) + 'info';
    $(infoSel).addClass('active-info');
  });
```

A much more elegant solution would probably be possible given the HTML, though.